# Find all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ that matrix $A$ is invertible

Tags: determinant

I have to find all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ that matrix $A$ is invertible.

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&1&1\\
1&2x&3&4\\
2&3&4x&5\\
3&4&5&6x
\end{vmatrix}
$$

I know that matrix is invertible, when $det(A)$ is not $0$.

So I got to this point 
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&1&1\\
0&2x-1&2&3\\
0&0&8x^2-8x-2&6x-6\\
0&0&4-4x&6x-6
\end{vmatrix}
$$

I did something wrong in between and if not,  what can I do next? I already tried to get $0$ where $4-4x$ is, but in the end I did not get the same result.

Result is $24(x-1)^2(2x+1)$

Comment: Please, don't delete your question after it has received an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could subtract the fourth row from the third, generating a zero there, then compute the determinant to be
$$
\det(A) = (2x-1)(6x-6)(4-4x) = (2x-1)(x-1)^2 \cdot 24.
$$
There is an error in your calculation. Here is my try to compute the determinant:
$$\begin{split}
\det\pmatrix{
1&1&1&1\\
1&2x&3&4\\
2&3&4x&5\\
3&4&5&6x}
&=
\det\pmatrix{
2x-1&2&3\\
1&4x-2&3\\
1&2&6x-3}\\
&=6
\det\pmatrix{
2x-1&1&1\\
1&2x-1&1\\
1&1&2x-1}\\&
=6
\det\pmatrix{
0&-2x+2&-4x^2+4x\\
0&2x-2&-2x+2\\
1&1&2x-1}\\
&=24 \det\pmatrix{1-x&2x(1-x)\\x-1&1-x}\\&
=24 (x-1)^2 \det\pmatrix{-1&-2x\\1&-1}\\&
=24 (x-1)^2 (2x+1)
\end{split}$$